# Spring AMQP Synchronous Transaction Rollback

Tags: spring-amqp

Spring AMQP Synchronous Transaction rollback does not work. Here DB transactions within the source are not handled by Spring. I need to have the Spring AMQP messages to be received and send within one transaction. Following are the snapshot of relevant code. Please let me know if you require anything else.

```
/////Connection Factory initialization

@Bean
public ConnectionFactory getConnectionFactory() {
    System.out.println("hello");
    configManager();
    String ip = ConfigManager.getQueueServerHost();
    System.out.println("IP Address : "+ip);
    CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(ip);
    connectionFactory.setUsername(ConfigManager.getQueueUserName());
    connectionFactory.setPassword(ConfigManager.getQueuePassword());
    connectionFactory.setPort(ConfigManager.getQueueServerPort());
    //connectionFactory.setPublisherReturns(true);
    //connectionFactory.setPublisherConfirms(true);
    return connectionFactory;

}

/////Rabbit Template initialization

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate producerRabbitTemplate() {
    RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(getConnectionFactory());
    rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(ConfigManager.getProducerQueueName());
    rabbitTemplate.setQueue(ConfigManager.getProducerQueueName());
    rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
    rabbitTemplate.setChannelTransacted(true);
    return rabbitTemplate;
}


/////Transactional Code

@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor=Exception.class)
public void processFile(RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate)throws Exception{
    rabbitTemplate.setRoutingKey(ConfigManager.getConsumerQueueName());
    rabbitTemplate.setQueue(ConfigManager.getConsumerQueueName());

    Object messageObj = rabbitTemplate.receiveAndConvert();
    Message message = null;
    try{
        if(messageObj != null){
            if (messageObj instanceof Message){
                message = (Message)messageObj;
                System.out.println("Message received is '" + message.getFileName() + "' for Hospital "+message.getHospitalId());
                String newFileName = this.process(message.getFileName(), message.getHospitalId());
                this.sendMessage(newFileName, message.getHospitalId());
            }else{
                System.out.println("Unknown message received '" +  messageObj + "'");           
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me; I just uploaded a [Gist with my test case](https://gist.github.com/garyrussell/6594677) that shows it working.

I suggest you turn on `TRACE` level logging to see all the transaction activity (and compare it with the log that I put in the Gist).

Comment: Thanks for the update and code. That code really helped. I was doing the same thing but with one issue. I was throwing Custom Exceptions instead of RuntimeException. That was the reason the transaction was not getting rollbacked.

Comment: Your `rollbackFor=Exception.class` should handle that. I just tested it with my test case and it worked fine - I updated the gist.